Audio mixing problem in cpp in windows
I am working on developing a screen recorder application using c++ in windows. In the application when I enable only output audio (i.e. speakers), the speaker audio is recorded smoothly without noise. Similarly, when I enable only input audio (i.e. microphone), the microphone audio is also recorded smoothly without noise. But when I enable both input and output audio and try to mix those two audio signals, the mixed audio became distorted. It makes me clear that the distortion or noise is occurred in the function in which I am mixing those 2 audio signals.
I have stored the input (microphone) audio and output (speaker) audio into 2 separated vectors named std::vector &inputAudio and std::vector &outputAudio respectively. The mixer function takes those two vectors as argument and return mixedAudio of type vector
I have tried to mix the input and output audio in two different approach. In first approach, I have tried to perform mathematical addition of each 8 bit (unsigned char) sample of input and output audio individually and pushed the mixed sample in the mixedAudio vector individually. But this approach adds noise in the mixedAudio.
Then, I came to know that the computer saves audio as 16 bit samples. That’s why, in the second approach, I have tried to perform mathematical addition of each 16 bit (i.e 2 successive bytes in the vector) sample of input and output audio individually and pushed the mixed 16 bit sample in the mixedAudio vector. This approach removes the noise but the mixedAudio is slightly distorted and the mixed audio seems to break for fraction of second after a few second every time.
I have provide the code of my two approaches here.
Approach 1(Adding 8 bit sample at each iteration)
static std::vector<BYTE> MixAudio(std::vector<BYTE> &first, std::vector<BYTE> &second)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> newvector; //this is the mixedAudio vector

    if (first.size() >= second.size())
    {
        // This will overlay both the samples
        newvector.insert(newvector.end(), first.begin(), first.end());

        for (int i = 0; i < second.size(); i++)
        {
            newvector[i] += second[i];
    }
    }
    else
    {
        //This will clip the second sample to the length of the first.
        vector<BYTE>::iterator end = first.size() > 0 ? second.begin() += first.size() : second.end();
        newvector.insert(newvector.end(), second.begin(), end);

        for (int i = 0; i < first.size(); i++)
        {
            newvector[i] += first[i];
    }
    }

    return newvector;
}

Approach 2(Adding 16 bit sample at each iteration)
static std::vector<BYTE> MixAudio(std::vector<BYTE>& audio1, std::vector<BYTE>& audio2)
{
    size_t minSize = audio1.size() < audio2.size() ? audio1.size() : audio2.size();
    std::vector<BYTE> result; //this is the mixedAudio vector


    // Mix the overlapping parts
    for (size_t i = 0; i < minSize; i += 2) {
        // Convert bytes to 16-bit integers
        int32_t sample1 = static_cast<int32_t>((audio1[i]<<8) | audio1[i + 1]);
        int32_t sample2 = static_cast<int32_t>((audio2[i]<<8) | audio2[i + 1]);

        // Mix samples and clip to the 16-bit range
        int32_t mixedSample = (sample1) + (sample2);
        if (mixedSample < -32768)
            LOGINFO(L"UNDERFLOWED");
            //if mixedSample is overflowed over 16 bit
        if (mixedSample & 0x10000)
        {
            mixedSample = (mixedSample & 0x0000FFFF) + 1;
        }
        //if (mixedSample > 32767) mixedSample = 32767;
        

        // Convert the mixed sample back to bytes
        result.push_back(static_cast<BYTE>((mixedSample >> 8) & 0xFF));
        result.push_back(static_cast<BYTE>(mixedSample & 0xFF));

        
    }

    // Append remaining samples from the longer vector
    if (audio1.size() > minSize) {
        result.insert(result.end(), audio1.begin() + minSize, audio1.end());
    }
    else if (audio2.size() > minSize) {
        result.insert(result.end(), audio2.begin() + minSize, audio2.end());
    }

    return result;

If anyone has experience of working on mixing speaker and microphone audio in cpp .Then please help me how I can mix audios without any noise

This is sort of difficult to diagnose not having the full story. How do you actually record output and input? Are they the same sample rate (48k?) and sample with (16 or 249? Does the files have a header describing the file format? What level are they both at, if both are normalized to 0dBFS adding them will overflow? A lot of questions. But as you have found it, randomly adding bits and bytes and words does not give you any pleasurable result.
